# Create new data.table column by applying function on other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a new column in a `data.table` based on the values of other columns. Using `mtcars` as an example:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
> head(dt[, newval := cyl + gear])
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newval
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     10
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     10
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      8
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      9
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     11
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      9
```

which works fine, but for even slightly more complex function, I get warning messages:

```
simple_func <- function(a, b){
  if(a %in% c(4,6)  ){
    return(a*b)
  }else{
    return(b/a)
  }
}

head(dt[, newval := simple_func(cyl, disp)])
```

returns:

```
> head(dt[, newval := simple_func(cyl, disp)])
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newval
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    960
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    960
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    432
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   1548
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   2880
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   1350
Warning message:
In if (a %in% c(4, 6)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

the value for row 5 (`cyl == 8`) is clearly incorrect and expected value of `newval` is 45.

The reason is that the function is not being evaluated one row at a time but for the entire column and therefore if the condition is met for the first row (`dt$cyl[1], dt$disp[1]`), all other rows have the same formula appllied to them.

How do I get around this? I tried using `.SDcols` but didn't get it right and got other errors instead.

Comment: `if` cannot be used on a vector condition.

Comment: What is the solution then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifelse`

```
simple_func <- function(a, b){
    ifelse(a %in% c(4,6), a*b, b/a)
}
```